# Crop a trapezoidal portion from a bitmap and create a rectangular resulting bitmap

Tags: android

I want to crop a trapezoidal part from a bitmap using four coordinate points that I have. And then get this cropped bitmap as an rectangular image as the resulting bitmap.

I want to do this with Android JAVA as I am not familiar with C++ native development or openCV for android.

Figure - 
[image: figure represents problem statement]

Comment: Pick the vertices of the trapezoid as source points, the vertices of the final rectangle as destination point. Find the transformation with findHomography, and use warpPerspective. Pay attention to the vertex order

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Set up a source polygon.  
    // X and Y values are "flattened" into the array.
    float[] src = new float[8];
    src[0] = x1;   // from your diagram
    src[1] = y1;
    src[2] = x2;
    src[3] = y2;
    src[4] = x3;
    src[5] = y3;
    src[6] = x4;
    src[7] = y4;

    // set up a dest polygon which is just a rectangle
    float[] dst = new float[8];
    dst[0] = 0;
    dst[1] = 0;
    dst[2] = width;
    dst[3] = 0;
    dst[4] = width;
    dst[5] = height;
    dst[6] = 0;
    dst[7] = height;

    // create a matrix for transformation.
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // set the matrix to map the source values to the dest values.
    boolean mapped = matrix.setPolyToPoly (src, 0, dst, 0, 4);

    // check to make sure your mapping succeeded
    // if your source polygon is a distorted rectangle, you should be okay
    if (mapped) {

        // create a new bitmap from the original bitmap using the matrix for transform
        Bitmap imageOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageIn, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    }
```